# how to seperate last and remaining all words in java?

Tags: java, string

What is the easiest way to get last word and remaining all words if the user enters multiple whitespaces?

```
String listOfWords = "This is a sentence";
String[] b = listOfWords.split("\\s+");
String lastWord = b[b.length - 1];
```

i expect the output like `lastWord = sentence`
and `firstWords = this is a`

Comment: have you tried splitting on a space? Just check if the last char is a . or ?

Comment: either way this will help you in long run https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 2):

```
String listOfWords = "This is a sentence";

String lastWord = listOfWords.replaceFirst("^((.*\\s+)?)(^\\S+)\\s*$", "$3");
String firstWords = listOfWords.replaceFirst("^((.*\\s+)?)(^\\S+)\\s*$", "$2").trim();
```

Identify the last word as `(\\S+)\\s*$` : non-spaces possibly followed by spaces at the end ($).

- Works *not* when there is no word
- Works when there is exactly one word
- Works when there are spaces at the end

Answer (score 1):

Here is quick fix for you. Check following code.

**Input :**

This is a sentence

**Output :**

First Words :This is a

Last Words :sentence

```
    String test = "This is a sentence";
    String first = test.substring(0, test.lastIndexOf(" "));
    String last = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
    System.out.println("First Words :" + first);
    System.out.print("Last Words :" + last);
```

Hope this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

To add one more answer using regex to split the sentence at the last space:

```
String listOfWords = "This is a sentence";
String[] splited = listOfWords.split("\\s(?=[^\\s]+$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splited));

//output [This is a, sentence]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying it's a good solution, however you can get the solution with below way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String listOfWords = "   This   is   a     sentence   ";
    listOfWords = listOfWords.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    String[] b = listOfWords.split("\\s+");
    String lastWord = b[b.length - 1];

    String firstWord = listOfWords.substring(0, listOfWords.length() - lastWord.length());
    System.out.println(lastWord.trim());
    System.out.println(firstWord.trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```html
System.arraycopy(Object[] src, int srcStartIndex, Object[] dest, int dstStartIndex, int lengthOfCopiedIndices);
```

Please check this:

```html
String listOfWords = "This is a sentence";
String[] b = listOfWords.split("\\s+");
String lastWord = b[b.length - 1];

String[] others = Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 0, b.length - 1);
//You can test with this
for(int i=0;i< others.length;i++){
    System.out.println(others[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String listOfWords = "This is a sentence";
    String first=listOfWords.substring(0,listOfWords.lastIndexOf(' '));
    String last=listOfWords.substring(listOfWords.lastIndexOf(' ')+1);
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is:

1. Trim the sentence using [`String#trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--).
2. Using the [`String#lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)), find the position of the last whitespace in the sentence.
3. Split the substring until the last whitespace using `\\s+` and join the resulting array using [`String#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-).

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String sentence = "     This      is       a            sentence";
        sentence = sentence.trim();

        int index = sentence.lastIndexOf(" ");
        if (index != -1) {
            String allButLastWord = String.join(" ", sentence.substring(0, index).split("\\s+"));
            System.out.println("First words: " + allButLastWord);
            System.out.println("Last word: " + sentence.substring(index + 1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Last word: " + sentence);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
First words: This is a
Last word: sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expression for perfect match

```
    String listOfWords = "This is a sentence";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)(\\s+)([^\\s]+?)$");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(listOfWords);
    while(m.find()){
       System.out.println("Last word : "+ m.group(3));
       System.out.println("Remaining words : "+ m.group(1));
    }
```

Where pattern "^(.+?)(\s+)([^\s]+?)$" works like below

^(.+?) - match all characters including space from the start(^) of the sentence

(\s+) - match more than one space if present

([^\s]+?)$ - match the last word by ignoring the space till the end($)

Output:

```
Last word : sentence
Remaining words : This is a
```